# How do i replace the value of a data-frame column with a single value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame column with string values like:

```
type      caught    bowled       hit
```

I want to change the complete column to 1. I tried this code:

```
ct['dismissal_kind']=1
```

But it didn't work. How can I change the values to 1?

Comment: Might be more helpful to have the full code (or at least more of it) for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

Solution1:-

```
pandas.concat([df['type'].dropna(), df['caught'].dropna(),df['bowled'].dropna(),df['hit'].dropna()]).reindex_like(df)
```

If you want that data to become the new column bar, just assign the result to `df['dismissal_kind']`.

Solution2:-

```
dataframe["dismissal_kind"] = dataframe["type"].map(str) + dataframe["cought"].map(str)+dataframe["bowled"].map(str)+dataframe["hit"].map(str)
```